# Create new column every hour with unique name

Tags: mysql, variables, events, mariadb, scheduler

I'm using MariaDB 5.2 and need to create a new column every hour, where that column needs a unique name. I have the following code, using time as an example:

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS calculation
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR STARTS '2021-01-01 00:00:00'
DO
SET @stmt := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE myTable ADD myColumn_', CURDATE() + 0, ' SMALLINT(5);');
PREPARE stmt from @stmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Unfortunately @stmt does not recalculate. It calculates it once when it first runs. And then with every iteration there after, it will just keep using the same value as before. How do I make it recalculate? I am using MariaDB 5.2.

It's also worth mentioning that if I simply run:

```
SET @stmt := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE myTable ADD myColumn_', CURDATE() + 0, ' SMALLINT(5);');
PREPARE stmt from @stmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

.. then it works the first time through without errors (the variable still will not re-calculate for later iterations). But as soon as I add in the CREATE EVENT code, I get an error: "SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1." There is no 'calculation' event when I run it so I don't understand how the first line could be null.

Comment: This is a fantastically implausible requirement. Either normalise your schema, or dispense with the need for an RDBMS.

Answer (score 2):

CURDATE() only returns a date, not a datetime. That is, it only has the year-month-day portion.

Example:

```
mysql> select curdate();
+------------+
| curdate()  |
+------------+
| 2021-05-30 |
+------------+
```

I could run that any number of times per day and it would always return the same value, because the date does not change (until you pass midnight).

I have to comment that adding a column every hour is an extraordinarily bad idea. Within a few days, you'll make a table with hundreds of columns. There's a practical limit to the number of columns in a table.

Besides that, if the table grows to a few million rows, you also have to consider it could take more than an hour to add a column. If it takes more than an hour to do that ALTER TABLE, and you run the event every hour, how do you intend that to work?

You really need to scrap this idea entirely and rethink the way you are storing data.

For example, add a *row* every hour, not a column.

Comment: Ohh ok. But what if I end up with like 7 million rows? Because this is the situation: Say I have 10,000 members, and I'm collecting a data point from them every hour, which is to be used to create a graph later on. There is a table that calculates these data points live. And then every hour I was going to copy a column from that table and paste it into another table. Which would be where the add a column comes into it. I have thought about adding it as a new row but that means that instead of having say 10,000 rows with max 744 columns, I would instead have about 7 million rows

Comment: .. each member number would be repeated about 700 times and each date would be repeated about 10,000 times. In other words my table becomes 3 times larger and 2 thirds of it is just duplicates

Comment: I work with MySQL tables with _billions_ of rows. MariaDB scalability should be similar to MySQL in this respect. I create 7 million row tables to run _tests_.

Comment: Really? So it's ok to have all those duplicates? Isn't it better to just add columns?

Comment: It's up to you. I can't say it's _never_ the preferred solution, because every rule has some exceptions. But I'd favor the solution that does not require me to ALTER TABLE every hour.

Comment: So that would mean it's also easier to add 10,000 rows that each span 3 columns than to add 1 column that spans 10,000 rows?

Comment: Yeah ok. I'm very new to database stuff so I don't know what direction to take. Someone else suggested I do the same. I just can't get my head around having 3 times more data where most is duplicates

Comment: Feel free to try it. You will get experience.

Comment: I can't figure out how to do it. But I can say that if I simply add a column it will take a few seconds where as adding a row is basically instantaneous

Comment: And my table right now only has 15 rows. So yeah adding rows is probably a better approach

Answer (score 2):

You seem to mixup a table and code.

A table should have a more or less fixed structure with a fixed number of columns. Since you seem te be working with some form of time series data it would be much smarter to arrange your table in a form where a part of your key is a timestamp and the other part of the key is your item's key.

Easiest is to generate the timestamp in the famous old unix format, seconds since epoch, what for unix means seconds since 1970. Have the client compute the date and time from that. This also makes sure you have no problems with timezone's because you store with UTC.

Doing so gives you the ability to select your data based on the key values and you can re-use your query.

With your original idea you would need to change your code for every range. That will be very hard to maintain and it also will not scale because of the table locking that occurs at every hour. A problem that will also quickly be solved because you will hit a max number of columns.

Comment: I like this idea. But even if I do add the data as rows I will still need to somehow get the date/time into the cells/fields (as either a concatenation with member number or just by itself in another column). If I write anything along the lines of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), etc. inside a event like above, it will give me an error, saying the value already exists, i.e. it's calculating CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() once and then just allocating it after each time interval. So I'm still at the same problem of not being able to force it to recalculate the time with each iteration.

Comment: Perhaps a database that allows me to add each data point as an element in an array would be better? Then I could just add it to the end and easily delete the first element. I don't know if that's a good decision though because I suspect an array in some sort of javascript object would be super slow.

Comment: OR maybe I could just create an algorithm in my web server that generates the timestamps and allocates it to the database? I'd have to run the event scheduler from my web app though, I don't know if that's a bad approach ?

Comment: Make it simple and simply use seconds since 1970 data. The formatting to date/time is a client thing. Forget about altering the table where an insert should be done instead.